# How do you exactly join two values from an excel sheet to get values?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib, accounting

so I'm pretty stuck with something, let me explain. So, I made some groupings to know the category from which each customer belongs to. However, I ordered them vertically so it took the list as columns, and have no idea on how to associate them.

```
customers = pd.read_excel (r'/xxxxx/customers.XLSX')

restaurants = customers['Restaurants'].tolist() 
restaurantsNoNAN = [item for item in restaurants if not(pd.isnull(item)) == True] 
print (restaurantsNoNaN)
```

So, at this point, I created the group of restaurants, which have all those customers that are restaurants. However, the problem arises in that, in order to know both the group and specific customer that buys products, I need to link both datasets. And the problem comes in that both are aligned in different ways. I made these examples that simulate the real files I'm working with. Consider that I have grouped both products and customers like the excel of the customer.

[Excel of Customers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oW75.png)

[Excel of Sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBFjO.png)

In this case, what would be the necessary step to align both, in order to be able to use matplotlib to get data?

Comment: Please do not include images of data. Always put your data (or a sample of your data) in text format, so it can be copy/pasted, or better still post python code that creates your dataframe. This way people will actually be able to use the data to try and reproduce your problem.  Also, please clarify what specific result you are trying to obtain.  You can [edit] the question.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, are you trying to join the `Customers` table and `Sales` table? if that is the case, maybe you can try `df_merge = pd.merge(Customers, Sales, left_on = 'Restaurant', right_on='Customer', how = 'inner')`